# RavenDB with MVC looking for wrong path and 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I'm following along with the RavenDB on Tekpub talking about using it with ASP.NET MVC.  I'm running the RavenServer.exe program on my local machine and I have a base controller set up as follows:

```
public class RavenController : Controller
{
    public new IDocumentSession Session { get; set; }

    private static IDocumentStore documentStore;

    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return base.Json(data, contentType, contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public static IDocumentStore DocumentStore
    {
        get
        {
            if (documentStore != null)
                return documentStore;

            lock (typeof(RavenController))
            {
                if (documentStore != null)
                    return documentStore;

                documentStore = new DocumentStore
                {
                    Url = "http://localhost:8080"
                }.Initialize();
            }
            return documentStore;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Session = DocumentStore.OpenSession();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        using (Session)
        {
            if (Session != null && filterContext.Exception == null)
                Session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a simple model defined using the sample Album data provided by RavenDB (also from the video):

public class Album
    {
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int CountSold { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

```
    public ArtistReference Artist { get; set; }
    public GenreReference Genre { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistReference
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GenreReference
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, here is my controller:

public class HomeController : RavenController
    {
        public ActionResult Album(string id)
        {
            var album = Session.Load(id);
            return View(album);
        }

```
}
```

Now, when I go to the URL `localhost:xxx/home/album/661` I get no result at all; debugging shows me that "album" is null so RavenDB isn't loading anything.  Looking at the server I see the following that it's getting a 404 requesting the path `/docs/661`.  However, when I go the album in question using the RavenDb studio, the URL it looks for (which returns data) is `/docs/albums/661`.  So it seems like I'm missing something somewhere to let RavenDB be able to find the documents via the MVC request, when it can find them correctly via the management studio.

Any ideas what I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WayneM,
Your problem is here:

```
public ActionResult Album(string id)
```

You are using a string id, but you are only passing the numeric part, RavenDB thinks you are giving it the full id, and tries to load a document with the id "661"

Instead, you can define it like this:

```
public ActionResult Album(int id)
```

RavenDB knows then that you are passing it a value type, and the conventions supply the rest of the id.

Comment: Ah great, thank you Ayende!  I guess that might have changed somewhere at some point, since in the video you're using `string id` just fine.